# Auto Renewing In-App Purchases Purchased Multiple Times

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am working on an App that will print labels at a store.  If I wanted to charge an Auto Renewing In-App purchase for each store the user wanted to add.  Say for example $5 / month / store.

How would I do that without creating an Auto Renewing In-App Purchase for 1 store, then a different subscriptions for 2 stores, then a different subscriptions for 3 stores etc..

Is there a way for the user to just keep purchasing the 'store' in app purchase each time they add a new store?  Perhaps then I could associate a receipt ID of some sort with each store to link the store to the in app purchase?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you printing physical label at physical stores? If so you might not be able to use In-App purchase since its only for digital goods. For physical goods you are not allowed to use in-app purchases. You have to find a 3rd party payment provider.

Comment: The payment would be for creating a store and tracking its associated data. Not the labels themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to do this with the way in-app subscriptions work currently.

My suggestions would be to create several tiers, (1-5, 5-20, 20+) as three separate priced subscriptions within the [same group](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/). If they are in the same group, you can initiate a purchase for the next tier and the user's existing subscription will be automatically upgraded.